# How should I declare an array that contains an array with 2 items without any in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, string, typescript, object, types

I am having an array like this:

```
protected arrayList: Array<any>;
arrayList = [["Wednesday"], ["Thursday"], ["Friday"]];
```

Then I want to assign a boolean value to the first element of the array by doing so:

```
this.arrayList[0].open = false;
```

So my array will be like this:

```
[["Wednesday", open: false], ["Thursday"], ["Friday"]];
```

If I change my declaration to `Array<string>`, the open property is not recognized as a value of the string.
How can I declare my array with other way than `Array<any>`

Comment: That last example is not valid javascript. You can definitely use something called a tuple, but to write a correct answer your question first needs to be fixed

Comment: *Maybe* the type you want is `Array<[string] & { open?: boolean }>`?  But I don't understand the use case.  Is each element really supposed to be an array of its own? If so, will it always have exactly one element?  Adding properties to arrays is probably not a great design because it's unexpected.  Maybe you can produce a [mcve] with enough info to demonstrate your use case?  Good luck!

Comment: @Evert no it is not a tuple. I did to assign the bool var to the first element of the array for expanding a list later.

Comment: @jcalz thanks. it works. I assign the bool var to the first element of the array for expanding a list later.

Comment: @KathrineHanson it doesn't change the fact that `[["Wednesday", open: false], ["Thursday"], ["Friday"]];` is not valid js/ts.

Comment: @Evert what would u suggest?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? I just mean that you should fix your code so it runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array<Array<any>>
```

should work fine.

You could just use JavaScript Objects with key-value pairs instead.
Example:

```
[{day: "Wednesday", open: false}, {day: "Saturday", open: true}]
```